# How to create a dropdown list for a input box depends on the value selected in another dropdown of another input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two input boxes as dropdown list. The dropdown list to be created for the second input box depends on the value given in the first input field.

```
var firstarray =[{sym: "1", desc: "one"},
                 {sym: "2", desc: "two"},
                 {sym: "3", desc: "three"}];

var secondarray =[{sym: "4", desc: "four", firstarraycode: "2"},
                  {sym: "5", desc: "five", firstarraycode: "2"},
                  {sym: "6", desc: "six",  firstarraycode: "1"}];
```

By using the first array I created the dropdown for the first input box.

The `sym` value of the first array is the third field (`firstarraycode`) of the second input box.

Depending on the `sym` value of the first array selection, the second input box's dropdown values must be filtered from the array.

For example, if we select `2` in the first dropdown list, it creates the second drop down list with `sym` values `4` and `5`.

Comment: Not Clear, Can you add an screenshot of what you want ?

Comment: also a jsfiddle would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Try : http://jsfiddle.net/aF6Xq/

```
var firstarray =[{sym:"1",desc:"one"},{sym:"2",desc:"two"},{sym:"3",desc:"three"}];
var secondarray =[{sym:"4",desc:"four",firstarraycode:"2"},{sym:"5",desc:"five",firstarraycode:"2"},{sym:"6",desc:"six",firstarraycode:"1"}];

function fillsecond(array){
   $('#second').empty();
   $('#second').append("<option>Select</option>");
   for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){             
     $('<option/>').val(array[i].sym).html(array[i].desc).appendTo('#second');
   }
} 
 $('#first').append("<option>Select</option>");
 $('#second').append("<option>Select</option>");

for (i=0;i<firstarray.length;i++){
   $('<option/>').val(firstarray[i].sym).html(firstarray[i].desc).appendTo('#first');
}
$('#first').change(function(){
  var val=$(this).val();

  var tempArray = $.grep( secondarray, function(elem){ return elem.firstarraycode  == val; });

  fillsecond(tempArray);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several jQuery utlities you can use like `$.map` or `$.grep` to filter the data.

```
$('#select_one_ID').change(function(){
  var val=$(this).val();
  var optionsArray=$.grep( secondarray, function(item){ return item.firstarraycode  == val; });

  /* loop over optionsArray to create new option tags*/

});
```

API Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/